# Проблема с обновлением .Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Добрый день. В связи с последними обновлениями студии, нужно также обновить Gradle. Если студия обновилась без проблем, то с gradle появилось куча ошибок. На данный момент, последняя версия gradle 2.13. Перепробовал кучу способов, но ничего не получается. 
В теле проекта есть папка со старой версией Gradle, как туда установить новую? Я потратил целый день, но так и не смог разобраться..

**Пробовал:**

1) в файле build.gradle установить зависимость  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.13'`

2) в файле проекта grandle-wrapper.properties указывал новую версию `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip`

3) в настройках проекта grandle ставил как

> Use default grandle wrapper

, так и

> use local distribution

Всегда появляется следующая ошибка:

> Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.13. Searched in
>   the following locations:
>       file:/C:/Program Files/Android/android-studio v3/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.13/gradle-2.13.pom
>       file:/C:/Program Files/Android/android-studio v3/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.13/gradle-2.13.jar
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.13/gradle-2.13.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.13/gradle-2.13.jar
>   Required by:
>       :myApp:unspecified

При попытке создания нового проекта пишет:

> Error:C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\2.10\scripts\asLocalRepo178_8nj2dccu0ba24ni5nnk1s7bux\cp_init\cache.properties
>   (Не удается найти указанный файл)

Т.е. студия ищет старый grandle, а как мне перевести её на новый?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В build.gradle, если у вас Android Studio 2.0

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
```

Если Android Studio 1,5

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

Откройте `Project Structure (Alt+Ctrl+Shift+S)` слева выберите `Project` и укажите `Gradle Version - 2.13`, `Android Plugin Version - 2.0.0`
Если все сделано, пробуйте собрать проект