# Gradle старая версия

Tags: android, android-sdk, gradle

Выдает ошибку: `Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE envrinment variable to...`

Как понял, нужно обновить `Gradle`, однако он для меня черный ящик, как с помощью студии не пытался пофиксить, так и не помогло ничего.

Сам `Gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.asgard.power"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

Как с этим быть?

Comment: Там обычно в самом сообщении о ошибке есть такая ссылка, что "обновить" - нажмите на нее и студия сама все сделает

Comment: Пробовал, оно ничего не изменило.

Comment: Спасибо за попытку помочь, решение нашел в этой теме: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517263/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-gradle?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего тебе нужно в файле      **gradle-wrapper.properties**

изменить строку  **distributionUrl**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Comment: Вообще не въезжаю, как это работает, честно.Позволяло бы время сесть и разобраться - но его нет, поэтому и пишу сюда.
Подскажите, на какую строку ее нужно изменить?

Comment: А сейчас у тебя там что ?

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'


    }
}

Только я не трогал gradle - wrapper.properties, а обновил студию, затем жмякнул фикс - и он предложил мне обновить **gradle**

Comment: А теперь посмотри что у тебя находится в gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: грэдл обновил, скорее всего надо задать distributionUrl для него

Comment: Возможно так будет понятнее
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572458/android-studio-2-0-plugin-is-too-old-please-update-to-a-more-recent-version

Comment: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip